# Как используя подписку на LiveData из ViewModel получать разные списки из одной таблицы базы данных Room?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, livedata

Есть база `Room`. Получаю весь список через `LiveData` и `ViewModel`.

**DAO:**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks")
fun getAllTask(): LiveData<List<Tasks>>
```

**Repository:**

```
fun getAllTasks(tasksDao: TasksDao): LiveData<List<Tasks>> {
    this.tasksDao = tasksDao
    return tasksDao.getAllTask()
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
class OwnViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: OwnRepository

    val allTasks:LiveData<List<Tasks>>


    init {

            val tasksDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).tasksDao()

            repository = OwnRepository()

            allTasks = repository.getAllTasks(tasksDao)

        }
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
class TasksFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var ownViewModel: OwnViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    ownViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(OwnViewModel::class.java)
}


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tasks_list, container, false)
        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.listTasks)

        // Set the adapter
        val adapter = MyTasksRecyclerViewAdapter(listener, context!!)

        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)


        ownViewModel.allTasks.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { tasksList ->
            tasksList?.let {

                adapter.setTaskList(it)
            }
        })

        return view
    }
}
```

Полученный список передаю в адаптер и заполняю `RecyclerView`

Есть необходимость получать из той же таблицы список не полный, а отфильтрованный по какому-то параметру.

Фактически сейчас при изменениях в базе адаптер получит новый список с изменениями. Но как правильно сделать чтобы получить отфильтрованный список?

Пару вариантов себе набросал.

**Первый вариант** -  который по логике должен быть сделан, это получить с базы новый список элементов, которые отвечают параметру `someId`, например таким запросом:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE some_id = :someId")
fun getTaskBySomeId(someId: Long): LiveData<List<Tasks>>
```

И потом передать в `Repository`, далее во `ViewModel` и далее в `adapter`. Но при попытке сделать эту передачу и заменить список в адаптере возникает куча нестыковок. Например пробую делать ветвление. Если `filterIsTrue == true` то делаю запрос на урезанный список:

**Переделанный ViewModel:**

```
class OwnViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository: OwnRepository

    val allTasks: LiveData<List<Tasks>>


    init {

        val tasksDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).tasksDao()

        repository = OwnRepository()

        allTasks = getTasksList(tasksDao)

    }

    private fun getTasksList(tasksDao: TasksDao): LiveData<List<Tasks>> {

        if (filterIsTrue) {

            return repository.getFilteredTasks(tasksDao, someId)
        } else {
            return repository.getAllTasks(tasksDao)
        }

    }
}
```

Но подписки на новую `LiveData` видимо нет, потому список и не обновляется. 
Была мысль убивать старую и получать новую `LiveData` и делать еще одну подписку. Не уверен, что это получится и уж очень запутанный код.

**Второй вариант** - сделать две `LiveData` и просто переключаться в нужный момент. Но тогда у меня будет висеть 2 подписки и каждый раз буду получать 2 списка во `ViewModel`: полный и частичный – нерационально, но проще. Можно ненужную подписку убивать и подписываться на новую `LiveData`, но это сложнее и все равно `ViewModel` будет получать 2 списка.

**Третий вариант** - делать выборку из полного списка по параметру уже в адаптере или перед передачей в адаптер. Не сложно, но теряется сама суть работы с базой. Получается что я буду получать каждый раз полный список, потом его перебирать, вместо того чтобы взять из базы маленький список и работать с ним.

Как лучше все же организовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того чтобы не создавать новых LiveData и не воротить костыли, создаем для неё геттер, таким образом всегда получаем один и тот же экземпляр LiveData на которую подписан наш Observer во Fragment:

```
ownViewModel.getLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { tasksList ->
    tasksList?.let { ... }
```

Заместо переменной лучше создать два метода для получения отсортированного или обычного списка, так будет проще и понятнее, далее просто присваиваем наш список LiveData через value, далее Observer получает новые данные и обновляет UI.

```
class OwnViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val repository = OwnRepository()

    private val allTasks = MutableLiveData<List<Tasks>>

    private val tasksDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application, viewModelScope).tasksDao()

    init {
        allTasks = repository.getAllTasks(tasksDao)
    }

    private fun getTasksList(tasksDao: TasksDao) {
        allTasks.value = repository.getAllTasks(tasksDao)
    }

    private fun getSortedTasksList(tasksDao: TasksDao) {
        allTasks.value = repository.getFilteredTasks(tasksDao, someId)
    }

    fun getLiveData(): LiveData<List<Tasks>> = allTasks
}
```

Из Room не обязательно возвращать LiveData, если не планируется отслеживать изменения в ней:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM tasks")
fun getAllTask():List<Tasks>
```

Могу посоветовать почитать [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/456256/) об архитектуре приложения от Google (ссылка на исходник там есть)

Если надо отслеживать БД, то можно воспользоваться следующим способом:

```
private val triggerLiveData: MutableLiveData<MyType> = MutableLiveData()
private val liveData: LiveData<MyType> =
    Transformations.switchMap(triggerLiveData) {
        myRepository.getRepoData(it)
    }

fun getData(value: MyType): LiveData<MyType> {
    triggerLiveData.value = value
    return liveData
}
```

Каждый раз, когда триггер будет изменяться, будет вызываться какой-то метод в каком-то репозитории + наш обсервер будет подписан на один экземпляр liveData, который будет получать данные из репозитория.

Comment: Как раз планирую отслеживание, это и стало основной палкой в колесах.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Не могу разобраться с кодом в дополнении. Что-то не стыкуется....не могу понять откуда вызывать  fun getData(value: MyType)

Comment: Могли бы Вы немного подробнее описать как можно применить Ваш код написаный  в дополнении?

Comment: Наверное лучше скину сэмпл, в нем как раз всё есть, не знаю разберетесь ли Вы в нем, но если разберетесь то это точно будет лучше, чем я тут просто сейчас напишу много букв в этом коменте. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/88747993139224a4bb6dbe985adf652d557de621/GithubBrowserSample

Comment: Разобрался. Ваш ответ очень помог!

Comment: Отлично! Всегда рад помочь :)